# SVG with image pattern only works in Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to get an image with an angle on the top, and the image needs to be updatable via a CMS. The most cross-browser compliant way I've found is to use an SVG, creating a path and giving it a pattern. The code I have right now is:

```html
<svg class="workIntroImage" width="696px" height="921px" viewBox="0 0 696 921">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="workIntroImg" width="1920" x="0" y="0" height="1080" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image xlink:href="https://www.usmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/147234372_the-office-zoom.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1920" height"1080"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g x="0" y="0" transform="translate(-37.000000, 0.000000)">
    <path x="0" y="0" d="M0,0 L725.886225,151.670321 C729.593802,152.445001 732.25,155.713561 732.25,159.501206 L732.25,928 L0,928 L0,0 Z" fill="url(#workIntroImg)"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

But it only works in Chrome - just shows up as blank in Firefox, Safari, and Edge. Any insight, or alternate solutions that will work in all modern browsers, would be appreciated!

Comment: You’re missing an `=` in `<image ... height"1080">` - is that just a transposition error?

Comment: That was it, not on purpose, I've just been staring at this for too long - thank you! If you can post this as an answer I'll mark it as correct!

Comment: @MTCoster the question should be closed as *simple typo issue* instead of being answred.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Good point - added my close vote

Comment: Is there a way for me to close it myself?

Comment: you can remove the accepted mark, so that MTCoster can delete his answer then you can delete the question .. or simply wait and it will get closed soon (still missing 2 votes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably just a typo - there’s an `=` missing in `<image ... height"1080">`. Chrome is good at parsing invalid markup, other browsers not always so much.

```html
<svg class="workIntroImage" width="696px" height="921px" viewBox="0 0 696 921">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="workIntroImg" width="1920" x="0" y="0" height="1080" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image xlink:href="https://www.usmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/147234372_the-office-zoom.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1920" height="1080"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g x="0" y="0" transform="translate(-37.000000, 0.000000)">
    <path x="0" y="0" d="M0,0 L725.886225,151.670321 C729.593802,152.445001 732.25,155.713561 732.25,159.501206 L732.25,928 L0,928 L0,0 Z" fill="url(#workIntroImg)"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you again! Will mark it solved in 5 minutes when it lets me!